# how to handle the passwords in an emm android app?

Tags: app-config, android-management-api, android-for-work, android-enterprise, emm

if i use the android managed configuration with all the app restrictions and so on... and the admin should set the credentials (example for a mail server) what is with security? All the values you define in the restrictions.xml file are set in plain text in the emm system. How can that be safe? and also if i understand everything right: the date also will send via google to the device... also in plaintext?

is there any different approach? or will all the restrictions send over the internet just always in plaintext?

thx

Answer (score 0):

When sending data to and from Android devices, Android uses [Transport Layer Security](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/12/an-update-on-android-tls-adoption.html) to provide communication security over the network. All data transferred to and from the server are encrypted. However, it’s bad practice to store passwords in plaintext, so we would advise not including a field for passwords in your app restrictions. Gmail, for example, includes app restrictions for use with Exchange accounts; it allows the admin to specify a certificate alias for logging in, but it does not allow the admin to share the user’s password via app restrictions (the user must login on the device).